# Laravel 8 eloquent query - Put external variable to 'Select after join'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Below is the code where I am getting relevant records by joining 3 table and then the 'Select' statement at the end is fetching specific fields. It's working perfectly. Now I want to add the variable '$userName' in to 'Select' statement to pass it with each record to view.
also I want the key of $userName as userName and the value is dynamic.

here is the code.

```
    $fromDate = request('fromDate');
    $toDate = request('toDate');
    $user = auth()->user();
    $userName = $user->name;
    
    $records = $user->cases()
        ->join('myrequests', 'mycases.id', 'myrequests.mycase_id')
        ->whereDate('myrequests.created_at', '>=', $fromDate)
        ->whereDate('myrequests.created_at', '<=', $toDate)
        ->select(
            'mycases.*',
            'myrequests.number',
            'myrequests.created_at',
            'myrequests.requested',
             **here I want the '$userName'**
        )->get();
```

I've tried `'username' => $userName` and `{{$userName}}`

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

you should get all the items from db then iterate over them:

```
 $records= ....

foreach ($records as $key => $item) {
   $item->username= $userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the string `$userName` returned as a 'username' column. If so, add a selectRaw.

```
$records = $user->cases()
        ->join('myrequests', 'mycases.id', 'myrequests.mycase_id')
        ->whereDate('myrequests.created_at', '>=', $fromDate)
        ->whereDate('myrequests.created_at', '<=', $toDate)
        ->select(
            'mycases.*',
            'myrequests.number',
            'myrequests.created_at',
            'myrequests.requested',
        )
        ->selectRaw('"?" as username', [$userName])
        ->get();
```

Comment: it returns error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range"